# Automatically save plots in ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to save to a different resolution all the plots generated in an ipython notebook. I know that I could add this line to each cell that shows a plot

```
plt.savefig('figure_1.pdf', dpi=300)
```

but that would require to add it manually when needed.

Is there any (reasonably) simple way to tell ipython to save each plot? Maybe by using a filename template like figure_X.pdf, where X is the cell's number?

Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/export-images-from-jupyter-notebook-with-a-single-command-422db2b66e92 extracts the base64-encoded images from the JSON of the notebook automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just dynamically create a variable that is your desired output name.

```
outPDF = 'figure_{}.pdf'.format(cellNumber)
plt.savefig(outPDF, dpi=300)
```

So for example, if `cellNumber = 5`, `outPDF = 'figure_5.pdf'`

Comment: Cool, thank you! Is there any way I can automate this? So that the savefig function is called automagically in every cell with a plot?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you're asking; this should just go into whatever other python code you've got that is generating/displaying the plots?

Comment: Yes, I would like to find a way to not have to write those two lines in every cell that displays a plot. Something like a magic function could do...